# Eighty percent of a hawk’s offspring are able to fly when they are pushed out of the nest for the first time. Let D denote the number of ...

Tags: probability

Eighty percent of a hawk’s offspring are able to fly when they are pushed out of the nest for the first time. Let D denote the number of chicks that fail to fly prior to a hawklet having a successful flight. Find P(D<2).

- Probability to fly: 0.8 & Probability to not fly: 0.2
- P(D<2) = P(D=0)+P(D=1)
- P(D<2) = 0.8 + (0.2)(0.8)
- P(D<2) = 0.96

I've been having a hard time understanding this material and am unsure if my thought process and answer is correct. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What is your thought process or answer?

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions my answer is 0.96 and my thought process is the bullet points.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.

Another way to obtain the result is to observe that $D < 2$ unless the first two hawklets pushed out of the nest both fail to fly, which occurs with probability
$$\Pr(D \geq 2) = (0.2)^2 = 0.04$$
Hence, the probability that the number of chicks that fail to fly before the first successful flight is less than $2$ is
$$\Pr(D < 2) = 1 - \Pr(D \geq 2) = 1 - 0.04 = 0.96$$

Comment: @user102156 if this answer was useful to you, you might consider accepting it - doing so improves your reputation score on the site (not to mention that of the person who helped you)